# A Journey through Known Territory

Tags: riddle

> Our journey begins, right in this place. Here, you will find many logical ace(s).
>
> So... Our next stop, whos title is an exception, there are many people with language connections. Unfortunately, it cannot point you to the next one, but, don't worry! There will be more fun.
>
> We'll descend a generation, to meet this recursive child. But don't be fooled, it's discussions aren't mild!
>
> Next, please meet my numerical friend. We were part of society, beginning to end.
>
> Now I will show you where everything starts. From definition to acquisition, the aliens have big hearts.
>
> Going in to the smaller places, we find place 2's fun brother. They like their answers short and pithy, unlike the others.
>
> I've shown you around, but there are many more. Try them out, they're not a bore; you can even earn a score!

To get your answer accepted, you must have the solution along with the meaning of every line.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is referring to

> [the Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com).

Our journey begins, right in this place. Here, you will find many logical ace(s).

> This is, of course, [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), with many lovers of logic.

So... Our next stop, whos title is an exception, there are many people with language connections. Unfortunately, it cannot point you to the next one, but, don't worry! There will be more fun.

> That's [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) - a common error (or "exception") in some programming *languages*. It doesn't have a list of the Stack Exchange network sites at the bottom.

We'll descend a generation, to meet this recursive child. But don't be fooled, it's discussions aren't mild!

> [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) is a child site of Stack Exchange, and it sounds like "see son". Seasonings are meant to make food *not* mild.

Next, please meet my numerical friend. We were part of society, beginning to end.

> [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), probably?

Now I will show you where everything starts. From definition to acquisition, the aliens have big hearts.

> This is [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), where new sites are created, starting at definition and ending at acquisition.

Going in to the smaller places, we find place 2's fun brother. They like their answers short and pithy, unlike the others.

> This is [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), whose questions were originally on-topic on Stack Overflow. The goal there is to solve a programming task with a file as short as possible.

I've shown you around, but there are many more. Try them out, they're not a bore; you can even earn a score!

> There are [dozens of other sites on the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), and you can earn reputation on all of them.

Comment: Very good! Some lines were not what I meant them to be, but your answers worked too. The "child" one was supposed to be meta, as it is a "child" of every site. "It cannot point you" refers to stack and heap. Stack is not dynamically allocated, so it has no "pointer".